# Meteor and Bootstrap admin

Tags: javascript, refactoring, meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to use meteor with a bootstrap admin, i.e. a bundle including several bootstrap plugins, script and everything typically made as a kind of framework for developing a web application.

Usually those bundles comes with a lot of dependencies, such as external links for fonts, IE hacks as well as their own shipped file of bootstrap, jQuery and other stuff. If we were in a regular php-like framework it would have been fine.

But in order to make such a template be "native" on meteor, I thought to refactor it in such a way that local dependencies (script and css basically) are stored into folders and not loaded via a `<script src="…"></script>` tag (otherwise the local path would not be found) but I doubt it is really the best practice, this is why I do consider 3 options:

1. To use the project/public folder in order to store all the bundle's dependencies (as if it would have been in php for example)
2. I might refactor the bundle's code by removing any `script` or `style` tag aimed to import the js or css into the page and add the corresponding js file aside so that meteor will dynamically load it during at runtime
3. Like in option 2 but instead of using the bundle's jQuery source files I would install the official jQuery's package for meteor (if existing).

The first (1) option should be the quickest one to get something running but it would not be very meteor native. The advantage however would be to keep the code near to the original one and being able to upgrade once a new version of the bundle would be released.

The 2 other options would be much more elegant (especially the third one) but it would involve a lot of refactoring and induce the risk of introducing bugs I did not expected.

My preference for now is the first option one but I'm afraid of not seing the drawbacks of this approach. Does someone have any experience in importing manually the CSS and JS files the "old fashion way" in meteor ? What is the risk of such an approach compared to using the "place in folder to include" way of meteor ?